# Connect to router acting as Wireless accespoint

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

In my network I have 2 routers. one acts as the DHCP server and this is where the internet cable goes into the house. I have the other one setup somewhere else to provide wireless for a different part of the house. Theres a cable between the two routers. My question is: How do I connect to the second router since the DHCP server is disabled? Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second router if you setup DHCP but for the gateway put in the first routers IP address. And for the second router the IP address should be assigned statically with the first router as the gateway. That should work.